# Best practice to take manage software dependencies for the development and prod environments

Tags: docker, dependencies, dependency-management

For a project that uses golang, python and runs on ubuntu linux, I am looking for a best way to manage software dependencies. For Go we use go modules and for python pip and anaconda. Many parts of the project are also dockerized (databases, mlflow server, etc).

I would like to have a system, that installs all the requirements automatically:

- go language
- python
- docker
- docker compose
- minikube for kubernetes
- linux programs such as jq, psql client

And at any time when there is a new addition to the dependencies, the system should execute required updates. For instance, we update the go version or add helm, and avoid that developers encounter errors when running the project.

I was considering maybe even developing inside a Docker container, that installs all the dependencies. But it seems like integration of GoLang with developing inside of the docker container is not out-of-the-box experience. Also, I would not want to be too dictative to the team. So, ideally, there should be a tool that installs everything on the local machine. And, a bonus point, if I could use the same tool inside of the docker if some of us do decide to develop inside of a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of tools and approaches that do what you're talking about, so there is no one answer.  At a high level, you need to choose how you want to distribute updates:

1. **OS Image** - use a tool like Hashicorp's packer to create custom OS images with all the pre-requisites.
2. **Container** - use a tool like docker to create containers with all your dependencies.
3. **Package level** - use a tool like ansible or chef or salt to install the dependencies you need.

Most people end up using a combination of the above eventually.

For what it's worth, if I were in your shoes I would start with ansible and work up from there.  It's a good tool and you can iterate into more complicated things if you want to.

An ansible playbook is a yaml file. For example:

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
      - name: install required packages
        apt:
           pkg:
           - golang
           - python3
           - docker
           - docker-compose
           - unattended-upgrades
           update_cache: yes
```

Execute it like so:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

Check it into source control and distribute to your developers, etc. etc.